# React native how to animate new prepended list element

Tags: listview, react-native

When the ListView renders the data source, it renders data to existing components, then creates new components as necessary.

Example: prepend(A) then prepend(B)

```
[ + A + ]
```

Later on

```
[   A   ]
```

Later on

```
[   B   ]
[ + A + ]
```

If the data is desc order, old data is rendered in a new component. You can imagine that makes my entry animation look ridiculous. How can i animate new data values if i can't trust `componentWillMount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the key property. then when component updates, the list element with the unchanged key will move to the new position, even if its index changes.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2219